# identify indices of selected values specific to a dataset column

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have to subset the given dataset based on the frequencies of a value in column `genus`.

```
msleep %>%
  group_by(genus) %>%
  count(genus) %>% 
  count(n)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       n    nn
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1    73
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     2
```

After looking at the output, I am interested in the values with a frequency 2. I obtained that using the below:

```
msleep %>%
  group_by(genus) %>%
  filter(n() ==2)

# Source: local data frame [4 x 11]
# Groups: genus [2]
# 
# # A tibble: 4 x 11
#         name  genus  vore          order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake brainwt bodywt
#        <chr>  <chr> <chr>          <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1      Horse  Equus herbi Perissodactyla domesticated         2.9       0.6        1.00  21.1  0.6550 521.00
# 2     Donkey  Equus herbi Perissodactyla domesticated         3.1       0.4          NA  20.9  0.4190 187.00
# 3 Arctic fox Vulpes carni      Carnivora         <NA>        12.5        NA          NA  11.5  0.0445   3.38
# 4    Red fox Vulpes carni      Carnivora         <NA>         9.8       2.4        0.35  14.2  0.0504   4.23
```

However, I would want to find the indices of these rows in the main dataset `msleep` when the actual values(`Equus`,`Vulpes`) are unknown. How to achieve this?

I achieved using this workaround. Is it the correct approach or any other efficient approach available?

```
msleep %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  group_by(genus) %>%
  filter(n() ==2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(rowid)

# # A tibble: 4 x 1
#   rowid
#   <int>
# 1    23
# 2    24
# 3    82
# 4    83
```

Comment: Maybe `which(with(msleep, ave(sleep_rem, genus, length)) == 2)`? (sleep_rem  could be replaced by any numeric variable).

Comment: Gives an error `Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :  unique() applies only to vectors`

Comment: Oops. i forgot FUN argument: `which(with(msleep, ave(sleep_rem, genus, FUN=length)) == 2)`.